# Installation from USB Stick on Thinkpad X240

Tags: 16.04, system-installation

I recently bought a used Thinkpad X240, with Windows 10 pre-installed. I want to use Ubuntu 16.04 as the only OS on that computer (thus remove Windows 10). Due to the lack of a DVD drive, I will have to install Ubuntu from a USB Stick.

Reading up on all the BIOS/UEFI changes has left me confused. What is the best way for me to install Ubuntu from a USB stick? Should I create it as a regular "BIOS install USB Stick", or follow the instructions to create a "UEFI install USB stick"?

Do I need to change any other settings in the BIOS/UEFI when booting from USB?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu tends to have issues with UEFI BIOS's. You should make a regular BIOS install USB stick and then your best option is to go into your BIOS (This is often achieved in Thinkpads by pressing the blue button on bootup) and change the UEFI setting to OFF. And then also disable "Secure Boot". Without these disabled, you will likely have a very difficult time installing Ubuntu. You will also probably need to change the boot order while you are there. So go into your boot settings in BIOS and change the boot order so that "USB Drive" or something similar is at the top of the list.

And that's all I can think of at the moment. After that your install should be pretty smooth. Just do a bit of research and make sure you know how to to get into the BIOS. Most laptops are different, but the most common keys to press are F12, F11, F2, F1, or DELETE.